# Scaling with AChartEngine

Tags: android, achartengine

Please excuse the very basic question, but I am very new to
AChartEngine. I tried out both a Pie and Bar Chart on my Samsung
Galaxy S2 and it displayed perfectly. However, on a HTC Wildfire, both
charts and labels only just fitted into the screen and so the display was
very messy.
How do you scale the charts for different sizes/resolution of
screens ?
Thanks very much
M

Jan, Taken your comment on board. Would you please be able to help me with an answer to my question.
Thanks very much
M

Comment: Can you post the xml you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is an old question but for anyone who needs it you can try doing this:

```
 DisplayMetrics dm = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
 float ScreenDensity = dm.density;
```

This will return the scale of the screen, 2 for xhdpi, 1.5 for hdpi, 1 for medium and 0.75 for ldpi. So you can use this to scale your margins and font sizes to help it fit on the screen.